# Can you call an external API to shorten links based on google sheets input?

Tags: ajax, google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet that contains links created after a form entry. I'd like to call the external API of a link shortening service (not google's link shorten-er) to take the link created in a given cell, shorten it, return the value and have Google Apps Script insert that shortened link into a new cell.

Is this possible? Specifically, can I use jQuery's AJAX methods? Where should I start.

Answer (score 0):

By checking the internet, I found this [stackExchange question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/76050/google-sheets-function-to-get-a-shortened-url-from-bit-ly-or-goo-gl-etc), you can try to follow the solution in this post. What you need here is **URL shortener API** under the resources in the script editor (Tools > Script editor) select the Advanced Google Services and activate the UrlShortener.

Here is the sample code that you need to use.

```
function onOpen() {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
.createMenu("Shorten")
.addItem("Go !!","rangeShort")
.addToUi() 
}

function rangeShort() {
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange(), data = range.getValues();
var output = [];
for(var i = 0, iLen = data.length; i < iLen; i++) {
var url = UrlShortener.Url.insert({longUrl: data[i][0]});
output.push([url.id]);
}
range.offset(0,1).setValues(output);
}
```

For more information, explanation and some sample pictures, just check the link above.